# can't change background color from .css stylesheet

Tags: css, html

[image]For some reason, I can't change my background color in a simple HTML page using a css style sheet.
I don't have any errors in my code, so this is weird.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Website/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is some content in the body</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm trying to do in my style.css file:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: are you loading the CSS? can you open it and see what is inside? did you clear cache? ..

Comment: Is your `style.css` located in a folder named `css` ? (maybe a dumb question because you do not have any error)

Comment: @yomisimie no it will work even if the body is empty due to background propagation

Comment: @Temani
Hi. yes, I can open the .css style sheet, I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. All the website's files and folders were directly created in the VS solution.
Also cleared Chrome cache. Not working.

Comment: @TemaniAfif My bad then, I had similar issues and I thought that might be it.

Comment: are you able to open it from the browser?

Comment: try open F12 and then on refresh button click right in mouse then click on `Empty cache and Hard Reload`

Comment: @Hearner. Yes, my stylesheet is located in a file named css.

Comment: Have you tried adding some content to the body?

Comment: Also tried this(but unfortunately not working with both):

 body {
  background-color: black;
  height:100%;
  height:auto;
 }

Comment: Tried to add some paragraphs, headings, unfortunately it's not working :)

Comment: It seems like it's not loading the CSS file. If you click on page source and then on the CSS url does it load?

Comment: then there must be an issue with your `href` try to check it in browser

Comment: try doing `href="../css/style.css"` or something like this for the correct path

Comment: I receive this error when inspecting the page: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: This is working on: http://localhost:12102/Website/Index.html

Comment: yes and that is because you are not giving correct path in `href` please post a screenshot of the file structure so that users can correct your reference path

Comment: @PopaAlin, your path is not correct. This is related to file / folder location of your environment. Besides, providing localhost addresses here is totally useless

Comment: added the structure

Comment: also, why is this so down-voted!? what the hell???

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. Apparently, the path in the **href** was wrong!!
When giving a path to a css style sheet, it begins to look in the folders located at the same root level.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is some content in the body</p>
    <p>This is some content in the body</p>
    <p>This is some content in the body</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great and dont get demoralize by downvotes, Happy Learning

Comment: Thank you Mohd Tabish Baig ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the href path. Start your path with "css/style.css" instead "/Website/css/style.css"